# Why I am not able to run Unicorn RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I am trying to install a RoR server on Amazon EC2 using Amazon Linux and Ansible. Everything goes through fine, at the end I am not able to run unicorn. I have checked that unicorn gem is installed

```
`gem list | grep unicorn`
```

showed unicorn installed.

When I type

```
`unicorn_rails`
```

I get command not found error. I checked my gem file and it has the line `gem unicorn` then I run `bundle install` and the output has `unicorn` in the list. Still not able to run it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can run `unicorn_rails`. Just use:

```
bundle exec unicorn -p <port> -c <path_to_config_file>
```

For example:

```
bundle exec unicorn -p 3000 -c ./config/unicorn.rb
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I thought I can just run unicorn_rails on command line. I kind of understand the concept of bundler but I thought I should be able to run on command line also. I have to put in under my ansible playbook, should I use bundle also in the playbook? How do I restart it then?

Comment: You can actually run `unicorn` if you are inside the rails directory, but not `unicorn_rails` since you installed `unicorn` only.

Comment: Makes sense. Actually, both unicorn and unicorn_rails worked under bundle exec. However when I execute unicorn in my Rails app directory I still get command not found error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bundler run unicorn with bundle exec:

```
$ bundle exec unicorn_rails
```

Find out more [here](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Sandbox.html).